# Chartkick with Google adapter stuck "Loading..." on Heroku Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, wicked-pdf, chartkick

My problem is that no matter what I try, I'm stuck with "Loading.." where I should have charts when I'm using chartkick and wicked_pdf.

Gemfile

```
gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge', '0.12.4.0'
gem 'chartkick'
```

Controller

```
respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render pdf: "FILENAME",
        template: "ratingreports/show.html.erb",
        window_status: "FLAG_FOR_PDF",
        margin:  {  top:               5,                     
                    bottom:            10,
                    left:              0,
                    right:             0 },
        background: true,
        page_size: 'Letter',
        default_header: false,
        footer: {
                  :html => {
                     :template => 'shared/footer.html.erb'
                  }
               }
      end
    end
```

pdf.js

```
setTimeout((function () {
    window.status = "FLAG_FOR_PDF";
    Object.keys(Chartkick.charts).forEach(function (key) {
        Chartkick.charts[key].redraw();
    });
}), 5000);
```

show.html.erb

```
head>
<%= javascript_include_tag wicked_pdf_asset_base64('pdf') %>
<%= javascript_include_tag wicked_pdf_asset_base64('loader') %>
<%= javascript_include_tag wicked_pdf_asset_base64('chartkick') %>
<%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
</head>
...
<%= column_chart @scorecount, colors: ["#46ceb7"], adapter: "google", discrete: true, height: "200px", width: "400px" %>
...
```

config/wicked_pdf.rb

```
if Rails.env.production?
  wkhtmltopdf_path = "#{Rails.root}/bin/wkhtmltox_0.12.5-1.xenial_amd64.deb"
else
WickedPdf.config = {
  exe_path: '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
}
end
```

I put loader.js and chartkick.js in my assets/javascript directories.  It's the only way I could get it to go from "no adapter found" to "loading" at least.

Comment: I should also comment that it works great in dev on localhost in both pdf and html formats, works fine on heroku html format...it's only when displayed as pdf that I'm stuck at loading...

Comment: I came here in the past and this helped me fix it. But now in 2021 this but is back. Anyone having this issue again too?

Answer (score 1):

Everytime...I work on something for a day, post it to stack, then I find the answer an hour later.

So, to fix this I had to remove (note: I "gem uninstall wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge", then removed from gemfile too, so it would remove the executible)

```
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge', '0.12.4.0'
```

and replace with

```
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-heroku'
```

and in wicked_pdf.config

```
if Rails.env.production?
  wkhtmltopdf_path = Gem.bin_path('wkhtmltopdf-heroku', 'wkhtmltopdf-linux-amd64')
else
WickedPdf.config = {
  exe_path: '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
}
end
```

Ding! Fries are done.  Hope that helps someone someday!  Finally, I can launch this product!